# Reading fixed doubles with fixed point from file and convert into long

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, rounding, numeric

I am reading US Dollar prices from a file. Example

```
asset_jsld 40.54
asset_sxd 40.80
```

I want to have a `map` that has these prices as a key. Since `float` or `double` are less than ideals keys, I am converting my values into Dollar Cents and I am storing them as a `long`. `words` is a list of `string` by column of the original file.

```
using boost::spirit::qi::parse;
// ...
if (!parse(words[1].begin(), words[4].end(), double_, price_d))
  // Error handeling
long price = boost::numeric_cast<long>(price_d * 100.0);
```

The problem is that the `double` is 40.80 and the `long` is `4079`. Does this rounding error come from `numeric_cast`? Is there are numerical stable alternative?

Comment: conversion from `double` to `long` are towards 0. So to have a correct rounding in your case, you can use `long price = boost::numeric_cast<long>(price_d * 100.0 + 0.5)` to round to almost the nearest, provided that `price_d >= 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do math operations on floating point numbers if you want consistency. Read the values as strings, remove the dot and parse that as `long`.

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)